# Ruby on Rails - incompatible marshal file format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently upgraded a Rails v3.x app to Rails 4.1.1 and everything seemed to transition for the most part, but however when I switch the app from production to development in the apache config file, I get the error message `We're sorry but something went wrong`  I know the development environment is working because I can see the GET request being processed in the `development.log` file.  But shortly after the GET request I get the following in the log

`ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
        format version 4.8 required; 123.34 given):`

Comment: Most likely you have session data that has serialised objects of classes that have changed between versions. Try deleting sessions. (A report on where exactly the error appears would probably be useful.)

Comment: How would I go about "deleting sessions" ?

Comment: Depends on what your `session_store` is configured to.

Comment: I'm not even using session variables in this app.  It's a pretty basic app, just a view controllers / views.

Comment: Then something else is getting serialised. Again, stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Well the whole idea of putting the app in development mode was to see the error messages in the browser, but this seems to not be the case at the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55105/discussion-between-chris-and-amadan).

Comment: I'm seeing the same error, (except the "version given" is 105.217, not 123.34) but the solution you found in chat isn't working for me (and this is Rails 3.2, so the serializer option below doesn't work either).

Answer (score 10):

In my case, this error was caused by me playing with the new `cookies_serializer` option in `config\initializers\cookies_serializer.rb`.

In development I set it to `:json` (which meant that my local cookies were serialized as json) but then I removed the option completely and put it in production. If I then ran the server in development again my json serialized cookies resulted in the same error.

So if you have ever run with `cookies_serializer` set to `:hybrid` or `:json` then you will need to carry on running with (at least) `:hybrid`.